# Database Queries without Model Objects on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Can I actually make database queries without creating a new instance of the model?

For example, in my controller I have (CONTROLLER)

```
Name_Model::get_all_from_another_table();
```

and in my name_model.php (MODEL)

```
public static function get_all_from_another_table() {
    $this->db->query('select * from another_table');
    return $x;
}
```

This case happens for tables with predefined values to be loaded before creating new instances of model.

The above code returns:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Comment: Why don't you try `$this->load->model('name_model')`? Do it on the controller. And we should do `$this->name_model->get_all_from_another_table()` to call it.

Comment: @Ukasyah `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context` . The same error occurs.

Comment: I think we can not use $this when we use "static" on the function

Answer (score 1):

Try it fisrt.

**Controller:**

```
 $this->load->model( 'name_model' );
 $data = $this->name_model->get_all_from_another_table()->result();
 print_r( $data ); //just for testing...
```

**Model:**

```
//Model name: name_model.php

public static function get_all_from_another_table() {
    $this->db->query('select * from another_table');
    return $x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Controller:***

```
// Model File and Class Name first Character Must be Uppercase

$this->load->model( 'Name_model' ); 
$data = $this->Name_model->get_all_from_another_table();
print_r($data); //You result is print here
```

***Model:***

```
//Model name: Name_model.php

public static function get_all_from_another_table() {
    $query = $this->db->query('select * from another_table');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, in CI 3 you can use lowercase when load it. Trust me, it works.

Comment: Ok maybe it is working but Some time it is affect so we have to take this good habit it is good for us.